# How to create Coulomb Matrix with Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, molecule

I need some coulomb matrices of molecules for a machine learning task.
Coulomb Matrix? Here's a [paper](https://nomad.fhi.mpg.de/) describing it

I found the Python package [molml](https://pypi.org/project/molml/) which has a method for it. However I can't figure out how to use the API for a single molecule only. In all [examples](https://github.com/crcollins/molml/blob/master/examples/simple.py) they provide the method is called with two molecules, why?

How the example provides the method:

```
H2 = (['H', 'H'],
      [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
      [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

HCN = (['H', 'C', 'N'],
       [[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

feat.transform([H2, HCN])
```

I need something like this:

```
 atomnames = [list of atomsymbols]
 atomcoords = [list of [x,y,z] for the atoms] 
 coulombMatrice = CoulombMatrix((atomnames,atomcoords)
```

I also found another lib ([QML](https://www.qmlcode.org/examples.html)) which promises the possibility to generate coulomb matrices, but, I'm not able to install it on windows because it depends on Linux gcc-fortran compilers, I already installed cygwin and gcc-fortran for this purpose.

Thank you, guys

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented my own solution for the problem. There's much room for improvements. E.g. randomly sorted coulomb matrix and bag of bonds are still not implemented.

```
    import numpy as np

def get_coulombmatrix(molecule, largest_mol_size=None):
    """
    This function generates a coulomb matrix for the given molecule
    if largest_mol size is provided matrix will have dimension lm x lm.
    Padding is provided for the bottom and right _|
    """
    numberAtoms = len(molecule.atoms)
    if largest_mol_size == None or largest_mol_size == 0: largest_mol_size = numberAtoms

    cij = np.zeros((largest_mol_size, largest_mol_size))

    xyzmatrix = [[atom.position.x, atom.position.y, atom.position.z] for atom in molecule.atoms]
    chargearray = [atom.atomic_number for atom in molecule.atoms]

    for i in range(numberAtoms):
        for j in range(numberAtoms):
            if i == j:
                cij[i][j] = 0.5 * chargearray[i] ** 2.4  # Diagonal term described by Potential energy of isolated atom
            else:
                dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array(xyzmatrix[i]) - np.array(xyzmatrix[j]))
                cij[i][j] = chargearray[i] * chargearray[j] / dist  # Pair-wise repulsion
    return cij
```

Comment: Any ideas on where the relation "0.5 * chargearray[i] ** 2.4" comes from? Besides the one-liner explanation in "Rupp et al Phys. Rev. Lett.,108(5):058301, 2012", do you know where can one find more detailed explanation of how this relation is derived?

Comment: It's probably very late for an answer (yeah 5 years late) but I found this:
"The main diagonal of the Coulomb matrix 0.5 Zi 2.4 consists of a polynomial fit of the nuclear charges to the total energies of the free atoms."  On this paper: Hansen, K. (2013). Assessment and Validation of Machine Learning Methods for Predicting Molecular Atomization Energies. J. of Chem. Th. & Comp.